# $_POST and tinymce not working in FF/IE

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, firefox, tinymce

So i have a textarea who use tinymce, it's displaying fine, i pre-filled the textarea from my database, it's work, the problem is that on firefox and on internet explorer, when i modify the content of the textarea, and when i click on "submit" the `$_POST['mytextarea']` have the same value than before.

If my textarea is pre-filled as "aaa" and that i modify by "aaabbb" the $_POST -> "aaa" but only in IE and FF. Why that ?

On Chrome or Opera when i modify by "aaabbb" the $_POST give me "aaabbb" like it should be.

EDIT:
Here is my textarea :

```
<textarea class="textpv" id="text" name="text" style="height: 300px;">
<?php if(isset($_GET['modele'])){$modele = $_GET['modele'];}else{$modele = '';}
if(isset($_GET['soc'])){$soc = $_GET['soc'];}else{$soc = $_SESSION['SOC'];}
echo htmlspecialchars(getcontentindatabase($soc, 'S', $modele)); ?>
</textarea><br>
```

who is called by this javascript when i change a option in a select

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
  menubar: false});

$('#modele').change(function(){
  $('#divwhocontainthetextarea').load(getContent('divwhocontainthetextarea'));
});

function getContent(x){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET', 
url:"textsign.php",
data:"modele="+$('#optionselect').val()+"&soc=<?php echo $_SESSION['SOC'] ?>",
success  : function(data){  
 obj=document.getElementById(x);
 obj.innerHTML = data;
 tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
 menubar: false});
}       
})
}
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Comment: Please put some code here, or try to reproduce it on a fiddle for us to debug.

Comment: @Bartdude i just edit the main post...

Comment: How do you get tinymce's content (javascript) from textarea? tinymce has its own functions for that

Comment: Have you tried to debug what is sent in your AJAX request ? TinyMCE probably doesn't update the content of your textarea before sending it for some reasons (and no, you're not actually yyping ito a textarea cause AFAIK wysiwyg editors like tinyMCE replace it in order to apply styling.

Comment: @vlzvl  i don't try to have the content with javascript, i try to get content via PHP, so i use $_POST['text'].

Comment: @Bartdude and how can i force the content of my textarea so ? ...

Comment: `..when i modify the content of the textarea, and when i click on "submit" the..` sounds to me like client's work sending the text, i might be wrong though..

Comment: @vlzvl The client send the text, and the server process it and record it in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correctly the content from a tinyMCE editor, you call it like that:

```
var content = tinyMCE.get("ELEMENT_ID").getContent();
```

or if you want the active editor, use this:

```
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

I'm not sure how you get the content, but if it's something like this:

```
var content = $("ELEMENT").html();
```

will just retrieve the **original** content and not the changed through editor.

**EDIT**

Here's a way of getting and sending the content to a PHP file using jquery

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET', 
   url:"textsign.php",
   data:{text:tinyMCE.get("ELEMENT_ID").getContent()},
   success:function(data) {
      alert("text sent");
   }
});
```

although this is just an example

Comment: Si i can't just get the content with PHP ? i must use javascrit... How can i do in javascript to send on submit the data to a processing page in PHP ?